# Assigning a variable a value from an recordset

Tags: php, sql

I apologize but I'm very new to PHP and I am trying to create a very simple form that sends an email back to a user when they enter in their email address. I want the message to include some data from our database.  I have been able to create a form that works perfectly as long as I enter in the message manually (like `$message = "Hi. How you doing?"`) but I can't seem to figure out how to incorporate the recordset data. What I was hoping was to use something like...

```
<?php 
  $to = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
  $message = '<?php echo $row_rsPersonUser['bio']; ?>';   <<<<<<<<Line 63

  $fields = array(); 
  $fields{"Email"} = "Email"; 

  $headers = "From: noreply@domain.ca"; 
  $subject = "Thank you"; 

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

What I get from this is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in.... on line 63".  I know it's formatted wrong but I don't have a clue why.  When I drop the  into the body, the info I want does display on the webpage so I know that part is working. Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use PHP start and end tags inside PHP code itself

```
$message = '<?php echo $row_rsPersonUser['bio']; ?>';   // this is wrong
            ^^^^^                                ^^
```

Should be

```
$message = $row_rsPersonUser['bio'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the 63rd line like below..

you can't start one `<?php` block in another `<?php` block

```
$message = $row_rsPersonUser['bio'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do that it would just print `<?php echo…` as literals since you can't send php code as a email only html/plan text

```
$message = '<?php echo $row_rsPersonUser['bio']; ?>';
```

should be:

```
$message = $row_rsPersonUser['bio'];
```

and (I tested the following and it appears the `{}`'s work but you might want to switch to only `[]`'s for standardization and not sure if you might get in trouble later on?)

FROM: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> Note:
> Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).

```
$fields{"Email"} = "Email";
```

should be:

```
$fields["Email"] = "Email";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already inside the php code, no need to add extra php start and end tags inside the variable name. Similar to how you have used the $to variable, you can use the $message variable.
So use

```
$message = $row_rsPersonUser['bio'];
```

and it would work fine.